# EEA Family Permit Application employment questions

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, uk-visa, family, eu-spouses

I have been filling the online EEA FP to join my wife in the UK. I have obtained several General visit visas to visit her on a regular basis before we got married. 
For these General visas, I have been feeling out the Employment and Income section.

This section happens to appear again under the EEA family permit and I'm confused because I don't need to answer any questions about finance or employment.

Are the questions in this section really relevant for the EEA Family Permit?

Employment:
What is your current working status?: Employed Full-Time
*
What is your total monthly income from all sources of employment or occupation, after tax?  N/A
*
Name of Company/Organisation/ Employer: N/A

*
Job Description / Title / Rank : N/A

*
Type of work undertaken: N/A

As I am employed do I still need to state my Company and Job Description?

For all the question about INCOME&EXPENDITURES, I answered N/A.

I am fully employed and I will be sponsoring my trip down to join my wife, does this means I still have to feel the Sponsor's details:

Are you being sponsored by a person(s)? 
Yes
No (No, for the reason explained above)

To prove that I will be sponsoring my trip to the UK, I'm thinking of providing my payslips and bank statements despite answering N/A to the question in the Income & Expenditure section

If I fill N/A to all financial employment questions about me(applicant) do I have to justify this in the Additional section, if so how could these be justified?

Could anyone with better experience in with the EEA PERMIT help with these doubts please.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that these questions are improper.  You may want to consider, however, that failing to respond to them might irritate the entry clearance officer considering your application, increasing the risk of a refusal.  It shouldn't be that way, of course, but in the end it is, because there is a person considering the application who may be swayed by emotions.

The information about sponsorship is also not particularly required, except that for the purpose of this application, *your wife* may be the sponsor because she is the EEA national through whom you derive your right of freedom of movement.  It doesn't matter who is paying the expenses.  You must therefore provide evidence of her EEA nationality and of her status as a "qualified person."  If there's nowhere else in the application to do this, then the "sponsor" fields are the appropriate place.

I'm writing with "if" because the last time I applied for an EEA family permit was several years ago now, and I do not remember as clearly as I used to, and anyway the form may have changed in the meanwhile.  I suspect that it hasn't changed much, however, because the inappropriate questions about finances have obviously not been eliminated.  When we applied, we did answer them all, but in that case it was for my mother in law, so it was necessary to establish that she was financially dependent.  For a spouse, it is not necessary to show financial dependence.