# EEA National Sponsor: EEA Family Permit Online Application

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, family, eu-spouses

I'm almost through filling the EEA Permit. I have answered every question regarding the applicant's employment, income as N/A. My doubts are in the EEA national section and sponsor's details:

> Are you being sponsored by a person(s)? Yes/No*

Do I have to fill in the details of the EEA national even when they won't sponsor my trip to the UK financially when the EEA Permit is granted or is there any other meaning to what they refer to has the sponsors details?

> How much is spent each month in GBP(£) on living costs?
>
> What is their total monthly income from all sources of employment or occupation, after tax?
>
> How much is spent each month in GBP(£) on living costs?*

These are questions previously asked about the applicant where I answered N/A. Now it asking about the EEA national. How have you answered these questions when the EEA national is already in the UK? N/A or the correct amounts?

Could anyone help out, please?

Answer (score 1):

When I did this, I put the EEA national as the sponsor.  That was my wife.  The application was for her mother.  If the question is about the EEA national, you must answer it with regard to your wife or your application may be refused.  This is because the facts you must prove for a successful application include your wife's EEA nationality and either that she is a qualified person or that she has been in the UK for no more than three months.

The information about living costs is not relevant for your application, but as I mentioned in my [answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/13498/2440) to another [question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/13492/2440) of yours, you may want to supply it anyway to avoid irritating the officer deciding your application.  If they use that information to refuse your application, you will have grounds for a complaint and an appeal.